# Typeahead: Getting undefined tags from remotely retrieved filtered data

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to properly configure the typeahead javascript module.
My aim is to retrieve tags from an array of json objects I can get from a remote url

here is the code I am using

```
var tagVals = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: { 
                url: 'http://...',
                filter: function (array) {
                    var res = [];
                    for (var index in array) {
                        var item = array[index];
                        res.push(item.name);
                    }
                    console.log(res);
                    return res;
                },
            },
        });
tagVals.initialize();
...
```

I can see the result returned by the filter is an array of names as I expected

the problem is that suggestions are all 'undefined'

Comment: Post a snippet of the beginning of your result array (you should also use `console.log()`, not `alert()` for testing). It's likely you're trying to access the wrong property or something in the `for` loop. Also, in general ask the specific question of the problem (*getting `undefined` displaying names from typeahead search result*), instead of guessing some downstream problem.

Comment: No Jared, the for is correct the log shows the result is indeed they array of names I needed (or at least that I guess typeahead needs)

Comment: It's part of the debugging and material to the question. Humor me. Sanitize the actual values if that's an issue. Another good option would be to make a working http://jsfiddle.net (you can use `/echo/jasn` and the data array given will be returned as the result).